# C# - MVC ApiController routing only returns a 404

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am trying to build a simple API using MVC `ApiControllers`. But it seems that my routing is incorrect, because I always get a `404` response code when I hit my endpoint.

I have the `ApiController` code:

```
namespace MyProject.Web.Controllers
{
    public class TestController : ApiController
    {
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [Route("test")]
        public IHttpActionResult Test() {
            return Ok();
        }
    }
}
```

And my WebApiConfig.cs is:

```
namespace MyProject.Web 
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config) 
        {
            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            var jsonFormatter = config.Formatters.OfType<JsonMediaTypeFormatter>().First();
            jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
        }
    }
}
```

When I go to the endpoint `http://localhost:7248/test` I get a `404` (NOT FOUND) error.
I've also tried removing `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();` and hitting the url `http://localhost:7248/api/test/test` but I still see a `404`.

I can't seem to make this work regardless of what I try. Does anyone see any place that I am going wrong?

Comment: what would happen if you remove the route("test") and change the method to GetTest() ?!

Comment: @DanHunex Stil a `404`. I'm at a loss here. Could it be something in the `web.config`? (although I'm not sure what to look for there)

Comment: Found the answer here: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/26171997/304684][1]
Odd one to have pop up.

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26171997/304684